# Как в react сделать вывод meta-тэгов на разных языках?

Tags: reactjs, i18n

Как в react перевести тэги на другие языки? Нужно это для SEO.
В своей программе я уже использую библиотеку `react-i18next`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать npm пакет  [`react-helmet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet).

Пример:

```
<Helmet 
   htmlAttributes={{ "lang": // язык вашего сайта en || ru  }} //
     meta={[
       { "property": "og:description", "content": а тут перевод   }
]} />
```

К атрибуту `meta`, можете добавить свои `meta` теги, которое хотите чтобы отображалось внутри тега `head`.

Альтернатива [`react-meta-tags`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-meta-tags)